# Webpack Karma middleware:source-files not showing requested object

Tags: angular, webpack, jasmine, karma-runner

I am following the tutorial [Angular/Webpack](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html) with one modification, the Angular app is located in src/ng2 instead of /src.

It works, when starting webpack-dev-server, but it fails loading all resources when starting karma. The following message is shown:

```
... :DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /[object%20Object] /
... :DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /[object Object]
... :WARN [web-server]: 404: /[object%20Object]
```

Most of other resources are shown properly with there name. How I can investigate which object causes the problem.

The full project is available on https://github.com/ManfredSteiner/app14. To reproduce the Problem call `npm run test2` (after npm install).

Comment: Change of source location does not have any influence. I build up the tutorial project exactly as described (Angular 2 app under _src_) and got the same effect.

Comment: The failing request concerns the image file `src/assets/images/angular.png`. If the *img* tag in `src/app/app.component.html` is removed, everything works without error. I guess, the problem is caused by the jasmine framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

karma.conf.js looks ok, however *null-loader* is used instead of required *file-loader* in **webpack.test.js**.

Replace section in webpack.test.js as per below:

from:

```
{
  test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
  loader: 'null-loader'
}
```

to:

```
{
  test : /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
  loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
}
```

and everything should works!